# what do i need to do images.preview: req.body.images.preview?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Here I want to create new post whith information about any film, but I've problem.
I've the model for films.

```java
    const FilmsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

      titleRus: {
          type:String,
          require:true,
      },
      ...(i hid a part of rhis code)
      images: {
          preview:String,
          poster:String,

      },
      videoURL:{
          first: String,
          second:String,
          third: String,
      },
      trailerURL:{
          first: String,
          second:String,
          third: String,
      },
      user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
          require:true,
      },
      }, {
      timestamps:true,
    })
```

Code for creating film.
Why I see this in console:

```java
    images.preview: req.body.images.preview,
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

what do I need to do?
I've the object **images** and I try to add information inside, but I see any problem.

```java
    export const createFilm = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const doc = new FilmsModel({
            titleRus: req.body.titleRus,
            titleOriginal: req.body.titleOriginal,
            ...(i hid a part of rhis code)
            images.preview: req.body.images.preview,
            images.poster: req.body.images.poster,
            videoURL.first: req.body.videoURL.first,
            videoURL.second: req.body.videoURL.second,
            videoURL.third: req.body.videoURL.third,
            trailerURL.first: req.body.trailerURL.first,
            trailerURL.second: req.body.trailerURL.second,
            trailerURL.third: req.body.trailerURL.third,
        });

        const film = await doc.save();
        res.json(req.body);

      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            message:'Не удалось создать пост'
        })
      }
    }
```